# Michelson Observation of White Light Fringes

Tags: optics, geometric-optics

Why are fringe diameters large near zero path difference, and why are the colours only visible near zero path difference?

Comment: Are you asking about the nonlinearity of the sine(theta) function (as applied to delta path lengths)?   Or about the lack of phase coherence for each "color" in the source white light?